# Использование импорта товаров из XML прайсов в WP All Import, как конкретно работает синхронизация? Cайт на WordPress, WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, xml, woocommerce, импорт, синхронизация

Если использовать импорт товаров из XML прайсов в WP All Import, то как конкретно работает синхронизация? То есть, если на сайте, у которого я импортирую товары, закончился, к примеру, 46 размер, то у меня на сайте это будет отображатся при синхронизации через WP All Import? Или как это вообще возможно сделать?

Comment: Что синхронизуруешь - то и будет. Прямо в WP All Import всё написано.

Comment: Хорошо, а есть какой то способ для синхронизации, как я указал выше?

Comment: -Вот сынок, это море. -де? ([анек](https://www.anekdot.ru/id/-1010200206/)). Блин. ЕСТЬ! И предвосхищая след вопрос - делается с пом. указанного  плагина (в других эта возможность тоже есть).

Comment: Хорошо, возможно ли это в бесплатной версии?

Comment: Ровно на столько насколько бесплатная работает с WC. Может ты уже сам попробуешь поставить и увидеть что он может? Или документацию почитать/посмотреть..

Comment: Бесплатная на работает с WC. Если товар отсутствует в xml в wp all import нужно указать скрыть/удалить товар если его нет в списке. А вообще смотрите документацию и читайте возможности плагина